# How to protect our code?

Tags: php, zend-guard

I have to protect my code? which is the best method for protecting our codes? any body can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you need to know is found at the Zend Guard Resources page:

- http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/resources